# Can EL call a nonpublic implementor of a public interface?

Tags: jsf, el

Java:

```
public class MyBean {
  ...
  public Handler getHandler(){  
    return new Handler(){  
      public void handle(ActionEvent e){...}  
    }
  }
  ...
}

public interface Handler{
  void handle(ActionEvent e);
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{myBean.handler.handle}"/>
```

I'm in a tomcat 6.0 environment. This is a common pattern in java, but it seems not to work with EL method bindings. I get an exception:

```
javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction SEVERE): Received 'java.lang.IllegalAccessException' when invoking action listener '#{myBean.handler.handle}' for component 'j_id115'
javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction SEVERE): java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.el.parser.AstValue can not access a member of class MyBean$1 with modifiers "public"
...
```

Comment: did you try making method `getHandler()` public?

Comment: yes, I forgot the keyword in the example above (fixed), thx :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was more subtle than I thought...

From java, there is no problem calling the public method in the inner class:

```
MyBean myBean = getMyBean();
Handler handler = myBean.getHandler();
handler.handle(event); // OK
```

Using reflection, it depends on how it's done. The method can be invoked as declared (1):

```
Method getHandlerMethod = MyBean.class.getMethod("getHandler");
Method handleMethod = getHandlerMethod.getReturnType().getMethod("handle", ActionEvent.class);
handleMethod.invoke(handler, event); // OK, invoking declared method works
```

Or it can be invoked as defined in the inner class (2):

```
Method handleMethod = handler.getClass().getMethod("handle", ActionEvent.class);
handleMethod.invoke(handler, event) // throws IllegalAccessException
```

Obviously, there's a third option, and it works (3):

```
Method handleMethod = handler.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("handle", ActionEvent.class);
handleMethod.invoke(handler, event) // OK
```

Unfortunately, my JSF environment (Tomcat 6.0 with JSF mojarra 1.2 and icefaces 1.8.2) implements approach (2) instead of (3) and therefore my example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, but you did a few things wrong.

First of all the `#handle()`-method has to be declared as public, because it is an implementation of the public method of your interface.

```
public class MyBean {
  ...
  public Handler getHandler(){  
    return new Handler(){  
      public void handle(){...}  
    };
  }

}
```

Second point is, that you are calling the Handler as your actionListener, but what you want is to call the #handle()-method:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.handler.handle}"/>
```

You also should omit the ActionEvent from the method-signature in your interface (and implementation)

```
public interface Handler {
  public void handle();
}
```

Comment: omitting the ActionEvent results in `Method not found: MyBean$1@7c353cc1.handle(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)`

Comment: which JSF version are you using? Please show your actual code + full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you specify the handle() method as ActionListener e.g.

```
<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{myBean.handler.handle}"/>
```

To specify an implementation class of ActionListener interface you can use the "f:actionListener" tag e.g.

```
<h:commandButton>
    <f:actionListener type="com.bla.SomeActionListenerImplementation" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But this wouldn't work in your case because your MyBean class doesn't implement the ActionListener interface...

Comment: yes, in my case it would not work, as I understand, also because `<f:actionListener>` needs to instantiate a class with zero-arg constructor, which doesn't work with an inner class